# How to set the initial offset of mongodb on nifi

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi, streamsets

**NIFI GetMongo**

With mongodb's_ ID is used as an offset to synchronize mongodb data, but no place can be set on the getmongo or getmongodrecord processor of nifi ???

Analogy: on streamsets, offset field and initial offset can be set

Comment: @mattyb    please help me, thanks

Comment: @mburgess  can you help me